# Disable oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, myfaces, flash-scope

I am using Apache MyFaces 2.0. I notice that a cookie `oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN` is getting created for each view, even though I am not using Flash scope and I have set `org.apache.myfaces.DISABLE_FLASH_SCOPE=true`.

How can I remove the `oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN` cookie?
This is WebSphere specific issue

Comment: @BalusC: thanks for edit. I am using IBM implementation of Apache MyFaces. Any suggestion on how to remove this cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed with WebSphere Fix Pack V8.0.0.6.
Refer http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM73173

Answer (score 8):

It's old thread, but it took me a while to find an answer, so I leave this for others... Should be:

```
org.apache.myfaces.FLASH_SCOPE_DISABLED
```

not DISABLE_FLASH_SCOPE. So in detail, add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.FLASH_SCOPE_DISABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to your web.xml.

Works good since 2.0.5.

Comment: I still see Set-Cookie: oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=-58grzla9l in response header after applying the above parameter